# Rejected - iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Tags: ios, ipad, appstore-approval

I need your help please.
I don't know how to resolve it. This is the message...

"
2.10 - iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

2.10 Details

We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9.1, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines. We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

Specifically, the buttons at the bottom of the app are inaccessible when running on iPad.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to ensure it runs at iPhone resolution on iPad.

Resources

For information on iOS device screen sizes and resolutions, please see the iOS Human Interface Guidelines as well as the Points versus Pixels in the View Programming Guide for iOS.

If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.

If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
- complete details of your rejection issue(s)
- screenshots
- steps to reproduce the issue(s)
- symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log.
"
Thanks!!

Comment: Did you test your iPhone app on an iPad or on the iPad simulator? Try it and see what looks wrong. Then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your next step is clear: test your app on an iPad. That's the only way to find the issue. Without more information, it is impossible to provide more guidance.